# Why do I get an invalid character type error when trying to sum integers?

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I am still a beginner practicing my R skills on one of the tidytuesday datasets.

My code is as follows:

```
library(tidytuesdayR)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tidytuesdayR::tt_load('2022-11-29')

wcmatches <- df$wcmatches

worldcups <- df$worldcups

penalty <- wcmatches %>% 
  group_by(win_conditions) %>% 
  count()

aggregate(penalty, list(number = penalty$n), FUN = sum)
```

What I am hoping for is the sum of all numbers in the n variable.

When I execute the last line, I get this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

I can't work out why given that error seems to relate to where the observations you're adding aren't the right data type e.g. they are characters? But everything in the n variable is an int which I checked with `class(penalty$n)` which returns integer.

Am sure as usual there's something simple going wrong .. any help appreciated.

Comment: `aggregate` converts all column of 1st arg, and 2nd arg of `aggregate` is grouping key. maybe what you want is `aggregate(penalty %>% select(-win_conditions), list(number = penalty$win_conditions), FUN = sum)`

Comment: To see the sum of `n` you don't need `aggregate`, you can sum directly `sum(penalty$n)`.

Comment: Thanks both. The sum approach worked. I had tried `sum()` but it was also throwing an error, something about the way I wrote it I'm guessing.

Your code cuttlefish44 still gave the same error I was getting.